# Rackspace and Progress bar

Tags: php, ajax, rackspace-cloud

I am using the Rackspace API and their FormPost which allows clients to upload files directly on the cloud.
So the form's target is a link they provided (I have no control over this one).
I also wish to have a progress bar for the uploaded files (which currently works).
However, rackspace's link by default makes a redirection when the upload is done, which contains some parameters in the link (error code and error message).
The thing is, since I am using AJAX for the progress bar, the redirection won't work, making me unable to get these parameters.

Do you have any good idea on how to do this ?
I am using PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: I think you need to have the control on the server to do this. In my case, the target page does not belong to me.

Comment: That makes me a sad Zoidberg. :E